# If a leg side wide ball is over the head of the batsman, will that delivery be counted as one-over-the-shoulder?

Tags: rules, cricket

The question is quite clear. Also, I have been asking around this question for long and I have been getting mixed responses. Some say it is counted as the first bouncer for the over and others don't believe that they are counted as one-above-the-shoulder. So it will be good if the answer is somewhat official - taken from the rule's book.

Comment: Which form of cricket is your question in reference to? The _Playing Conditions_ for international cricket differ from the standard _Laws_ that apply to club cricket, for instance.

Comment: International cricket, ofcourse!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per ICC's standard [ODI match playing conditions <sup>PDF</sup>](http://icc-live.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/media/about_docs/524ac4ae08b48-04%20Standard%20ODI_2013_19%2009%2013.pdf), law 42.4.1 states that:

> ... d) ...a ball that passes above head height of
>   the batsman, that prevents him from being able to hit it with his
>   bat by means of a normal cricket stroke shall be called a wide.
>
> e) For the avoidance of doubt any fast short pitched delivery that
>   is called a wide under this playing condition shall also count as
>   one of the allowable short pitched deliveries in that over.

So, the answer is **YES**. It will be counted as one over the shoulder.

Answer (score -1):

The leg side wide which has been bowled over the head of the batsman is not considered as one-over-the-shoulder for the following reasons

1. For umpire to warn the bowler as one-over-the-shoulder the ball should be bowled to the batsman body which makes it as a dangerous ball.
2. Here in this case ball has been bowled leg-side so no its not going to do any damage to batsmen to consider it as a dangerous ball more-over most of the times it will be accounted as a wide for bowling leg-side rather than considering it as a wide for going over the top of the head.

Comment: Any rules regarding this?

Comment: I dont know whether there is any rules about this but I have seen a match in which umpire giving it as a wide for the above mentioned scenario

Comment: In the above scenario giving a wide signal is obvious. But what about one bounce signal?

Comment: No umpire did not indicated the one bounce for the over

Comment: A rule that supports your answer will be very helpful because I have gotten an answer (with a proof in the form of a rule) which says that it will be counted as one over the shoulder.

Comment: @Salihdeen - Then add your own answer with linking that law.

Answer (score -3):

As far as I have seen, there are no specific rules mentioning this case. Some matches I have seen umpire calling it as just wide and some cases, it is also called as over the shoulder too. So the answer is it depends on the umpire, just like how LBW is called when player steps out of the crease.

Comment: n00bLord's answer contains a quote from the ODI playing conditions. Where did you look? (And the stuff about LBW and stepping out of the crease is pretty much wrong as well).